# How to handle the key property in angularfire5

Tags: angular, firebase, key, angularfire2, angularfire5

As we all know there were breaking changes to the angularFire api in version 5. For example, in my data service I previously had a methods like this:

```
getBookings(): Observable<Booking[]> {
    return this.db.list('bookings');
}

update(booking: Booking): void {
    this.db.object('bookings/' + this.getFireBaseKey(booking)).update(booking);
}

private getFireBaseKey(b: Booking): string {
    return (<any>b).$key;
}
```

Now, after upgrading to angularFire5 I have the following issue: As I want all firebase-related stuff to be encapsulated in my service and not leak to the rest of the application I want to expose rxjs Observables from the service. Hence I either have to add a call to `valueChanges()` in the `getBookings()` - but then I loose the `$key` (which I need in the update later), or to `snapshotChanges()` where I map it as follows:

```
getBookings(): Observable<Booking[]> {
    return this.db.list<Booking>('bookings')
        .snapshotChanges()
        .map(changes =>
            changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
        );
}
```

The latter (kinda) requires me to extend my Booking model by a key property, and I can adjust my `getKey` method accordingly.

But now the awkward part comes: Updating the booking will lead to a weird data structure in the Firebase db with the key present as 'list-key' and as key property on the 'list-object'.

What is the recommended way? I see two options, both of which are not really satisfactory to me:

- Delete the property from the `Booking` instance before updating
- Not add it ot the Booking model? Then we have an untyped property and 'magic' leaking to the application outside the service.